# Why is Textarea component displaying it's text value in a white or transparent color?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I have a Textarea component used from [ChakraUI](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/form/textarea) that's displaying text inserted in my container component called BookReview as a text prop called "bookReview".
It's supposedly picking up the bookReview prop and displaying it in a textarea on an edit button click for the user to edit the text. It has worked the first time I implemented it, however, when I tried to test it today, I got the strange bug mentioned in the title.

```
import { AccordionItem, Box, AccordionIcon, AccordionPanel, PopoverTrigger, PopoverContent, PopoverArrow, PopoverCloseButton } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import * as React from "react";
import { Accordion, AccordionButton, Popover, Button, PopoverHeader, PopoverBody,Textarea } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const BookReview = ({ bookReview }: { bookReview: string }) => {
  
  const [isClicked,SetIsClicked] = React.useState(false);
  let [areaReview,setAreaReview] = React.useState(bookReview);
  let [review,setReview] = React.useState(bookReview);
  
  const editClickHandler = () => {
    SetIsClicked(current => !current);
  }
  
  const saveClickHandler = () => {
    setReview(areaReview);
  }

  return (
    <>
     <Accordion allowToggle w={"100%"}>
     <AccordionItem>
     <h2>
   <AccordionButton>
     <Box flex="1" textAlign="left">
       Review
     </Box>
     <AccordionIcon />
   </AccordionButton>
   </h2>
   <AccordionPanel pb={4}>
     {review}
       <Popover>
         <PopoverTrigger>
           <Button float={"right"} size="sm" onClick={editClickHandler} p={3}>
             Edit
           </Button>
         </PopoverTrigger>
         <PopoverContent>
           <PopoverArrow />
           <PopoverCloseButton />
           <PopoverHeader>Edit review</PopoverHeader>
           <PopoverBody zIndex={"base"}>
           <Textarea placeholder='your review' resize="vertical" value={areaReview} onChange={(e) => setAreaReview(e.target.value) } variant={"md"} />
           <Button variant={"ghost"} bg="red.500" float={"right"} marginTop={3} onClick={saveClickHandler}>
             Save
           </Button>
           </PopoverBody>
         </PopoverContent>
       </Popover>
    </AccordionPanel>
     </AccordionItem>
     </Accordion>
    </>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your “bookReview” prop received in BookReview is undefined ? also check by adding debug point what value you are passing to TextArea

Comment: I tried to log it to console and it did log but I also got an uncaught reference error. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: May be it logged for the first render and due to some operation the value isn’t in memory or it is set to undefined maybe on next render